# Class singleton's initialization cann't be done automatically

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, singleton

I have made a class singleton as follow:

```
class AccountManager
{
    static let sharedInstance = AccountManager()

    private init(){
        print("init is done if this message shows up")
    }
}
```

Which I thought the `init` method would implement automatically once I have launch the app without invoking `AccountManager.sharedInstance` in some place first, but actually it won't unless invoking `AccountManager.sharedInstance` specifically first.

Is this behavior normal or I have done something wrong?

Comment: It's normal. The singleton have to be used somewhere to be created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A static type property is initialized lazily (and only once), i.e. it is initalized on the first
access, e.g. if you call

```
let manager = AccountManager.sharedInstance
```

or

```
AccountManager.sharedInstance.someMethod()
```

**Swift provides *no* mechanism to execute code automatically at runtime.**

In Objective-C you could implement a [`+ (void)load;`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1418815-load?language=objc) method which is run when the class is loaded into memory, this is not permitted
in Swift.

Comment: Thanks for the decisive answer, @MartinR.  (Re the other question, I had not even heard of "main.Swift"  :-)  )